# Chrome dev tools - Save for override does not work

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I am trying to save a js file in a designated folder for chrome override files, and whenever I press right click then "Save for override", the file wont save in the folder. \

Note.

1. Source --> Enable Local Override is on.
2. In other websites the tool is working properly and saves files.
3. The above problem occur in a localhost website through weblogic, therefore I must use dev-tool override

Comment: Maybe the path exists only in sourcemaps but devtools can work only with real paths?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was receiving `Changes to this file were not saved to file system.`.

This is despite the override working in other pages.

In my case the issue was the `url address`.

If i have `https://mystite.com/my-page-to-override` it won't work, but if i change it to  `https://mystite.com/my-page-to-override/` then in the `Page` tab i see a new folder with an index page in it and it works.

**Url format**

```
[NOT WORKING] https://mystite.com/my-page-to-override
    [WORKING] https://mystite.com/my-page-to-override/
```

**In the page panel**

```
top
 - mysite.com
   - my-page-to-override
     - (index)
```